# python Spectrogram by using value in timeseries

Tags: python, time-series, spectrogram

I am new to spectrogram and try to plot spectrogram by using relative velocity variations value of ambient seismic noise.

So the format of the data I have is 'time', 'station pair', 'velocity variation value' as below. (If error is needed, I can add it on the data)

```
2013-11-24,05_PK01_05_SS01,0.057039371136200
2013-11-25,05_PK01_05_SS01,-0.003328071661900
2013-11-26,05_PK01_05_SS01,0.137221779659000
2013-11-27,05_PK01_05_SS01,0.068823721831000
2013-11-28,05_PK01_05_SS01,-0.006876687060810
2013-11-29,05_PK01_05_SS01,-0.023895268916200
2013-11-30,05_PK01_05_SS01,-0.105762098404000
2013-12-01,05_PK01_05_SS01,-0.028069540807700
2013-12-02,05_PK01_05_SS01,0.015091601414300
2013-12-03,05_PK01_05_SS01,0.016353885353700
2013-12-04,05_PK01_05_SS01,-0.056654092859700
2013-12-05,05_PK01_05_SS01,-0.044520608528500
2013-12-06,05_PK01_05_SS01,0.020226437197700
...
```

But I searched for it, I can only see people using data of network, station, location, channel, or wav data.

Therefore, I have no idea what I have to start because the data format is different..

If you know some ways to get spectrogram by using 'value' of timeseries.

p.s. I would compute cross correlation with velocity variation value and other environmental data such as air temperature, air pressure etc.

###Edit (I add two pictures but the notice pops up that I cannot post images yet but only link)

I would write about groundwater level or other environmental data because those are easier to see variations.

The plot that I want to make similarly is from David et al., 2021 as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR0Gp.jpg)

X axis shows time series and y axis shows cycles/day.

So when the light color is located at 1 then it means diurnal cycle (if 2, semidiurnal cycle).

Now I plot spectrogram and make the frequency as cycles / 1day.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WOLB.png)

But what I found to edit are two.

1. In the reference, it is normalized as log scale.
   So I need to find the way to edit it as log scale.
2. In the reference, the x axis becomes 1*10^7.
   But in my data, there are only 755 points in time series (dates in 2013-2015).
   So what do I have to do to make x axis to time series?

p.s. The code I made

```
fil=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
cf=fil.iloc[:,1]
cf=cf/max(abs(cf))

nfft=128     #The number of data points
fs=1/86400   #Hz [0, fs/2] cycles / unit time

n=len(cf)
fr=fs/n

spec, freq, tt, pplot = pylab.specgram(cf, NFFT=nfft, Fs=fs, detrend=pylab.detrend, 
window=pylab.window_hanning, noverlap=100, mode='psd')

pylab.title('%s' % e_n)

plt.colorbar()
plt.ylabel("Frequency (cycles / %s Day)" % str(1/fs/86400))
plt.xlabel("days")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you want to plot it using matlab or some other program language?

Comment: Oh sorry I did not mention it. I use python. I saw that people usually use matplotlib.pyplot.spectrogram and scipy.signal.spectrogram.

Comment: Perhaps you need FFT or DFT (Fast Fourier Transform - Descrete Fourier Transform). I know that there is something simillar for sound signals using pyaudio, matplotlib and pyqt5.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at it, `wav` data is basically just an array of numbers (sound amplitude), recorded at a certain interval.

**Note:** *You have an array of equally spaced samples, but they are for velocity difference, not amplitude. So while the following is technically valid, I don't think that the resulting frequencies represent seismic sound frequencies?*

So the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (in the form of [`np.fft.rfft`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html)) would normally be the right thing to use.
If you give the function `np.fft.rfft()` *n* numbers, it will return *n*/2+1 frequencies. This is because of the inherent symmetry in the transform.

However, one thing to keep in mind is the *frequency resolution* of FFT. For example if you take *n*=44100 samples from a `wav` file sampled at Fs=44100 Hz, you get a convenient frequency resolution of Fs/*n* = 1 Hz. Which means that the first number in the FFT result is 0 Hz, the second number is 1 Hz et cetera.

It seems that the sampling frequency in your dataset is once per day, i.e. Fs= 1/(24x3600) =0.000012 Hz. Suppose you have *n* = 10000 samples, then the FFT will return 5001 numbers, with a frequency resolution of Fs/*n*= 0.0000000012 Hz. That means that the highest frequency you will be able to detect from data sampled at this frequncy is 0.0000000012*5001 = 0.000006 Hz.
*So the highest frequency you can detect is approximately Fs/2!*

I'm no domain expert, but that value seems to be a bit low for seismic noise?

Comment: Thank you for your help. May I ask you one more? Why is  Fs 0.000012 Hz when the dataset is once per day and does FFT return 5001 when I suppose n=10000samples?

Comment: @Joe See updated answer on Fs. The returned length is half of the number of samples because the other half would be negative frequencies IIRC, symmetric to the positive frequencies.

Comment: Thank you so much. I could understand more than before. I add my codes, plots, and two questions in the post. I know I already got a lot of helps from you but could you please let me know more? (And the value is really low because it is ambient seismic noise which has much lower amplitude than other ordinary seismic data)